# Image not moving when setting style.left property

Tags: javascript

I created a `setTimeout` function which sets the `style.left` property of the image to 100px after 3 seconds.

I did call the function.

I have tried replacing `'100px'` with `100 + 'px'` and it still did not work.

```
<img id="my-Image" src="image.jpg">

function threeSec() {
  setTimeout(setProperty, 3000);
}

function setProperty() {
  document.getElementById('my-Image').style.left = '100px';
}
```

When inspecting the html, I can see that style="left: 100px" is being appended to the image property but the image itself did not move.

I expect the image should move.

Comment: Is the image by default with `position: absolute;`?

Comment: No, I changed the position to absolute and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is the position of the image is not set to absolute. Setting the image position to absolute solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set your image position to absolute like shown below,

```
<img id="my-Image" style="position: absolute;" src="image.jpg">

function threeSec() {
  setTimeout(setProperty, 3000);
}

function setProperty() {
  document.getElementById('my-Image').style.left = '100px';
}
```

For more, refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_left.asp).

Comment: @Vega Ooops! When I was trying, answer was not updated in my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Better change the position to relative instead of absolute else you might face some design issues where image is ignoring its parent division.